# Optional filter on a left join column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having issues wrapping my head around how to write a procedure that includes an optional filter on a left join.

I have two tables, Issues, and Customer_Location.  Not all issues have been linked to a customer location.  So I am fine with this as a starting point:

```
SELECT
  I.Issue_Number,
  C.Customer_Location_Code

FROM Issues I
LEFT JOIN Customer_Location C
  ON C.Customer_Location_Key = I.Customer_Location_Key


Issue_Number | Customer_Location_Code
1            | Chicago
2            | NULL
3            | Chicago
4            | New York
```

And this works, it gives me all the issues.  But I want to add an optional parameter for the customer location code that if left null would return all 4 issues, but if set to say 1 for Chicago, only issue 1 and 3 would return.

I've tried this

```
DECLARE @customer_location_key INT
SET @customer_location_key = 1

SELECT
  I.Issue_Number,
  C.Customer_Location_Code

FROM Issues I
LEFT JOIN Customer_Location C
  ON C.Customer_Location_Key = I.Customer_Location_Key
 AND C.Customer_Location_Key = @customer_location_key
```

But I get the following results

```
Issue_Number | Customer_Location_Code
1            | Chicago
2            | NULL
3            | Chicago
4            | NULL
```

For some reason I seem to be having a brain fart right now and just can't seem to get my head around what **SHOULD** be something rather simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a where clause similar to below should do it.

```
DECLARE @customer_location_key INT
SET @customer_location_key = 1

SELECT
  I.Issue_Number,
  C.Customer_Location_Code

FROM Issues I
LEFT JOIN Customer_Location C
  ON C.Customer_Location_Key = I.Customer_Location_Key
where (@customer_location_key is null or C.Customer_Location_Key = @customer_location_key)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the where clause instead

```
DECLARE @customer_location_key INT
SET @customer_location_key = 1

SELECT
  I.Issue_Number,
  C.Customer_Location_Code

FROM Issues I
LEFT JOIN Customer_Location C
  ON C.Customer_Location_Key = I.Customer_Location_Key
WHERE
 (@customer_location_key is null OR C.Customer_Location_Key = @customer_location_key)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your query does not work as you expect is that first the 2 `ON` conditions are examined and then, because of the `LEFT JOIN`, all rows of table `Issue` that haven't been matched are added as well (with NULLs in the columns of table `Customer_Location_Code`).

```
DECLARE @customer_location_key INT
SET @customer_location_key = 1

SELECT
  I.Issue_Number,
  C.Customer_Location_Code

FROM Issues I
LEFT JOIN Customer_Location C
  ON C.Customer_Location_Key = I.Customer_Location_Key
WHERE ( @customer_location_key IS NULL )
   OR ( C.Customer_Location_Key = @customer_location_key )
```